# Guardar html en mysql por formulario

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, jquery

Hola estoy haciendo un proyecto el cual requiere que guarde HTML insertado en una caja de texto dentro de un formulario, el envió del formulario se realiza por medio de ajax y el guardado lo relaizo con php, ya he intentado con esto:

```
function htmlEncode(value)
{
  return $('<div/>').text(value).html();
}

htmlStr = htmlEncode($('.caja').val());
```

pero no funciona por los caracteres especiales "&", que cortan la cadena, alguien tiene alguna sugerencia para realizar la operación de guardado a bd y recuperar de bd con php? gracias por su ayuda de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

yo te recomiendo que codifiques tu formulario en base64 antes de enviarlo, así:

```
function htmlEncode(value)
{
  return window.btoa(value);
}

htmlStr = htmlEncode($('.caja').val());
```

Y una vez recibido en tu archivo php lo decodificas así:

```
$htmlStr = base64_decode($_POST['htmlStr']);
```

Saludos.

Comment: gracias, voy a probar, si me funciona te marco tu respuesta como valida.

Comment: Vale, prueba y me cuentas.